# Qt Data Type Choice

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, types

I'm trying to pass a large quantity of data that is being pulled from a set of textboxes.  The data is in the formats '+1.59', '-2.52', and some ints.  Also, to make things more interesting there is a varying number of SETS of textboxes.

I was looking into using QVariantMap, but extracting the data and putting it into a QByteArray after was proving to be difficult.  I also considered using a QByteArray, but parsing through it over and over didn't seem appropriate.  I would prefer a data type that I can reference the items name -- i.e. data["preX1"].

What would be the best approach?  Please provide a basic example of the types usage if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the data comes from *text* boxes, I would pass it around as text until you parse and validate it. Once validated, you'd typically use pass the different values to some constructor, to group all the values in one object.

Comment: Agree, numbers in QString are converted to numerical primtives via it's own methods very easily and safely too.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be only decimal numbers. In that case, a vector of floats would probably be the most efficient:

```
typedef std::vector<float> FloatVector
FloatVector yourData;
```

---

If it's not just floats, then a vector of variants would be enough (no need for a map):

```
typedef std::vector<QVariant> VariantVector
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's all coming from text boxes you might as well use something like QStringList unless you really, really need them as a QVariant, Qt themselves recommend using the lists for speed and efficiency, listed in the [QVector details](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvector.html#details) from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data represents floats, I agree that you should probably go with a data structure that holds floats rather than QVariants.  If you want to be able to reference items by name, you're going to want to use a QMap or a QHash.  QHash is faster, but QMap values are sorted by key if you iterate through them.  The data type that you used, QVariantMap, is just a `QMap<QString, QVariant>`, where the QString is the key data type for the map, and the QVariant is the value data type for the map.

I would go with a `QHash<QString,float> floatMap`.  To convert the data from the text boxes, you can just use `QString::toInt()`.

```
QHash<QString,float> floatHash;
QString textBoxString;
QString textBoxName;
floatHash[textBoxName] = textBoxString.toInt();
```

to access the data, use:

```
float value = floatHash[textBoxName];
```